# load previously saved XML file in a grid c#

Tags: c#, xml, grid

Greetings to everyone.

I need a Windows Forms application that will use the created DLL library to load previously saved XML file, and to display the following information about found files in a grid with the following columns: “File name”, “Parent folder”, and “Executable type”.
I added a reference to dll file in WF prodject.

I would appreciate any help.

I made it so far with the code

//ClassLibraryDLL.Class1.SaveXml();

```
    //Create xml reader
    XmlReader xmlFile = XmlReader.Create("directory.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    //Read xml to dataset
    ds.ReadXml(xmlFile);

    foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["dir"].Rows)
    {
        int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();

    }
```

XML file

```
     <dir name="smiley">
          <dir name="fun">
            <file name="aiua.gif" />
            <file name="ak.gif" />
            <file name="alien.gif" />
            <file name="alien2.gif" />
            <file name="angry.gif" />
            <file name="angry1.gif" />
            <file name="apophys.gif" />
            <file name="assjani.gif" />
            <file name="asthanos.gif" />
            <file name="bazuzeus.gif" />
            <file name="beaute.gif" />
            <file name="bigsmile.gif" />
            <file name="blush.gif" />
            <file name="boid.gif" />
            <file name="bonk.gif" />
            <file name="bored.gif" />
            <file name="borg.gif" />
            <file name="capo.gif" />
            <file name="confused.gif" />
            <file name="cool.gif" />
            <file name="crazy.gif" />
            <file name="cwm14.gif" />
            <file name="demis_roussos.gif" />
            <file name="devil.gif" />
            <file name="devil2.gif" />
            <file name="double0smile.gif" />
            <file name="eek3.gif" />
            <file name="eltaf.gif" />
            <file name="gele.gif" />
            <file name="halm.gif" />
            <file name="happy.gif" />
            <file name="icon12.gif" />
            <file name="icon23.gif" />
            <file name="icon26.gif" />
            <file name="icon_angel.gif" />
            <file name="icon_bandit.gif" />
            <file name="icon_bravo.gif" />
            <file name="icon_clown.gif" />
            <file name="jesors.gif" />
            <file name="jesors1.gif" />
            <file name="lol3.gif" />
            <file name="love.gif" />
            <file name="mad.gif" />
            <file name="megaphone.gif" />
            <file name="mmm.gif" />
            <file name="music.gif" />
            <file name="notify.gif" />
            <file name="nuts.gif" />
            <file name="obanon.gif" />
            <file name="ouaip.gif" />
            <file name="pleure.gif" />
            <file name="plugin.gif" />
            <file name="question.gif" />
            <file name="question2.gif" />
            <file name="rasta2.gif" />
            <file name="rastapop.gif" />
            <file name="rosebud.gif" />
            <file name="sad.gif" />
            <file name="sad2.gif" />
            <file name="shocked.gif" />
            <file name="sick.gif" />
            <file name="sick2.gif" />
            <file name="slaap.gif" />
            <file name="sleep.gif" />
            <file name="smile.gif" />
            <file name="smiley_peur.gif" />
            <file name="sors.gif" />
            <file name="sovxx.gif" />
            <file name="spamafote.gif" />
            <file name="tap67.gif" />
            <file name="thumbdown.gif" />
            <file name="thumbup.gif" />
            <file name="tigi.gif" />
            <file name="toad666.gif" />
            <file name="tongue.gif" />
            <file name="tuffgong.gif" />
            <file name="urgeman.gif" />
            <file name="vanadium.gif" />
            <file name="wink.gif" />
            <file name="worship.gif" />
            <file name="wouaf.gif" />
            <file name="wow.gif" />
            <file name="xp1700.gif" />
            <file name="yltype.gif" />
            <file name="yopyopyop.gif" />
            <file name="youpi.gif" />
            <file name="zoor.gif" />
     </dir>
```

and its showing me only the results in Parent folder. How can get the file in File name column. Here is how the xml looks like. And here is my form. 
So i need a file name to be under File name column. The parent folder of the file to be in the Parent folder column and the type of the file to be in Executable type column.

Comment: You need to ask an actual question. This is far too broad for anyone to be able to offer you advice or code assistance. No one writes programs here, just helps correct issues and errors. So start the project and ask questions when you hit a road block you can't get past.

Comment: Do have a look (in the debugger) into your table! Does it have all columns you expect?

Comment: yes it has all columns.

Comment: OK, but I see you load only the 2nd one into a dgv column (`dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();`). So what is the question?

Comment: thats because i dont know how to load it correctly. As I sad file name should be under "File name" column. The parent folder of the file should be in the "Parent folder" column and the type of the file to be in "Executable type" column. Don't know how to write a code.